# Runnable jar cannot find project jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

I have an old project in Eclipse, I used to export it as a runnable jar w/o problems.

I'm trying to export it as a runnable jar now, but when I try to run it, it cannot find the project jars like the `mysql-connector.jar`

I added the jars by doing **"Build path > configure build path > Add Library > Created a user lib with the external jars > added to project"**, after that the project runs in Eclipse w/o a problem.

I can actually open the runnable jar, it shows the login screen (the first GUI on my software)
but when I try to log in, it doesn't find the `mysql.jar`...

When I run it from Eclipse, it works perfectly fine.

So far I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not setting a classpath that includes the dependent jars?

Comment: When building your runnable jar, did you check "Package required librairies into generated JAR" ?

Comment: @DaveNewton The classpath is set te way i posted, i added then to the classpath by doing "Build path > configure build path > Add Library > Created a user lib whit the external jars > added to project"

Comment: @ortis I ussualy use "Extract required libraries into generated JAR", but i also used "Package required libraries into generated JAR"
Both give me the same problem, when i run they dont find the jars.
I even tryied the third option of creating a folder "next to it" whit the jars, but it also didnt work

Comment: When you unzip the jar, can you find the external JAR you added to your classpath ?

Comment: @ortis No. But on eclipse it seens fine, but inside the jar theres only the src

Comment: @ortis i removed all the jars and re-added then, not using a library just used add external jar, selected all the jars and then exported.
It worked, i dont know what i was doing wrong...

Comment: Wait, how did you import your Jar in Eclipse ? The proper way is to use "Add External JARs" not "Add Library". The added Jar should NOT appear in the Package Explorer frame.

Comment: @ortis i imported the jars like the mysql.jar to eclipse, first i was using add library and on that library i was adding the external jars.

Comment: Thats not how it should be done. Just use the "Add External JARs"  and the "Package required librairies into generated JAR" when building runnable jar.

Comment: @ortis i see, thanks for helping, doing like that seens to be working fine.